# Wordpress home page not centered

Tags: php, wordpress, alignment, html

[Why is my "Page [0]" not centered in my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540540/why-is-my-page-0-not-centered-in-my-webpage)

is the closest I've found yet to the type of problem I'm having.

The home page of my site is not centered. When you click on any secondary page it will center.

I have Googled at least 100 times for every article on centering a web page with CSS using several search terms. I have even replaced style.css with a freshly downloaded copy of the theme style.css file with no change.

I fixed one custom template page that was doing the same thing by adding:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>
```

I tried doing that with the home page but it still did not fix it. The home page will still not center.

The theme is supposed to be HTML5, I ran it through a validator and it gives errors for the rel statements, but that should eventually be fixed when they get the validator updated. No relevant CSS seems to be a problem to the validator.

When I do clear: left in #primary of the Layout section, it fixes the problem, but the right sidebar widget goes down the page.

I also fixed the duplicate #wrapper entry that comes as a default with the Twenty Ten theme.

I don't recall having the problem before the Wordpress 3.2.1 update, but then again I may not have noticed it.

It's the same in Firefox and IE.

You can see it at http://www.danmctaggart.com

Comment: It looks centred for me, in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. Haven't got IE around to test with. What does it actually look like for you? Is it to the left or the right? All the way or just a bit?

Comment: (Also, what duplicate #wrapper? I'm using vanilla Twenty Ten on one of my blogs and it doesn't have a duplicate #wrapper. Is this a documented problem?)

Comment: When you click on the home page link and then click on any page link you will see the entire wrapper move to the left by a few pixels. In reference to the duplicate #wrapper entries, in the theme css there is a #wrapper included with some other id's and then #wrapper by itself directly underneath. Instead of having duplicate entries for #wrapper, I unified the #wrapper id and put all of it's parameters under one entry. That is what I meant.

Comment: '/* The main theme structure */
#access .menu-header,
div.menu,
#colophon,
#branding,
#main,
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 940px;
}
#wrapper {
 background: #fff;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}'  Note how margin is defined in both #wrapper statements, once as margin: 0 auto; and then margin-top: 20px; @Matt Gibson

Comment: Ah! I thought you were talking about a duplicate #wrapper in the HTML (which would be illegal, of course), not in the CSS...

Comment: As for the actual centring, I think I'm with @Jimmy on this one. The reason I'm not seeing the problem is because I'm using OS X Lion, which has "disappearing" scrollbars that don't affect the page width.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't programming related at all.

Your homepage is not very tall, so it doesn't have a vertical scroll bar. Your other pages are. It *seems* like it isn't centered, but it's really just re-centering with the addition of a scroll bar on the right.

Comment: You can switch from page to page and the content does not move. Once you click on the Home link, it does move. In fact, the entire wrapper moves.  I forget to mention one bizarre fact, that if I am logged in as admin and that dashboard menu bar at the top of the browser window is active, the site will stay centered.  I just logged out and will stay logged out for a time so that it can be seen.  @Jimmy

Comment: I checked with Photoshop to be sure. Home Page 190px from the left margin, sub pages are 179px from the left margin. That's not re-centering. @Jimmy

Comment: @Dan Erm. It is re-centering if your page width gets smaller by 22 pixels because the scrollbar appears... In Photoshop, how far is Home Page from the right margin, and how far are the sub pages from the right scrollbar that appears? Also, can you post a picture of the home page you're seeing and one of the sub-pages (even a short horizontal slice of the pages would do...)? Because I can't reproduce your problem at all, it's hard to tell if we're talking at cross-purposes or not...

Comment: Incidentally, to see if it is the scrollbars, try adding `body { overflow-y: scroll }`, which should force the vertical scrollbar to appear in most browsers, regardless of the content height.

Comment: body { overflow-y: scroll } appears to have fixed the problem. I must say I was skeptical about it, but tried it anyway. That thing is locked in the center of the page and no scroll bar is showing in IE on the front page, which is ideal. Couldn't be better. Thank you very much. @MattGibson Hopefully the moderator will leave this post up for all the people who have been frustrated by this esoteric problem.

Comment: @Dan I would accept this answer -- Jimmy was quite right; this is simply because of the way scroll bars work in web browsers.

Comment: @MattGibson  I accept that the answer is the scroll bars, but just  knowing that does not fix the problem.  The solution for the moving #wrapper is     body {overflow-y: scroll}  The wrapper no longer shifts, the page is now locked in place, the problem is solved.

Comment: In other words, without the CSS and seeing it fix the problem, I likely would not have believed it was the scroll bars.  Since Jimmy kind of got the ball rolling, thanks to him as well.  @Jimmy